# Is there a way to get the average of a dynamic criteria within a specific criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to get the average of the hour count per Serial # and per Date value. Getting the total count is easy but I can't get the dynamic unique value for the dividend (highlighted in green). The only way I know in getting the average is create a pivot and then calculate the average manually. Which is shown on the screenshot below. Is there a way to get it by just using an excel formula?

The average of range `H10:H13` will reflect on cell `O8` and range `L10:L11` is on cell `O9`.

[image]

---

| Serial # | Hour Count | Date Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 04:00 AM | 4/25/2022 |
| 10001 | 01:00 AM | 4/26/2022 |
| 10001 | 02:00 AM | 4/25/2022 |
| 10001 | 02:00 AM | 4/26/2022 |
| 10001 | 03:00 AM | 4/25/2022 |
| 10001 | 01:00 AM | 4/25/2022 |
| 10001 | 02:00 AM | 4/25/2022 |
| 10001 | 03:00 AM | 4/25/2022 |
| 10002 | 03:00 AM | 4/25/2022 |
| 10002 | 04:00 AM | 4/26/2022 |
| 10002 | 01:00 AM | 4/26/2022 |
| 10002 | 04:00 AM | 4/25/2022 |
| 10002 | 01:00 AM | 4/26/2022 |
| 10002 | 02:00 AM | 4/25/2022 |
| 10002 | 01:00 AM | 4/26/2022 |
| 10002 | 03:00 AM | 4/26/2022 |
| 10003 | 03:00 AM | 4/26/2022 |
| 10003 | 03:00 AM | 4/26/2022 |
| 10003 | 02:00 AM | 4/25/2022 |
| 10003 | 02:00 AM | 4/26/2022 |
| 10003 | 04:00 AM | 4/25/2022 |
| 10003 | 04:00 AM | 4/25/2022 |
| 10003 | 03:00 AM | 4/25/2022 |
| 10003 | 01:00 AM | 4/26/2022 |

Comment: What version do you have? Office 365 has some new functions that would make this easier.

Comment: And can you put your Sample table in as text in your question so we do not need to retype it all?

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner, unfortunately I am using a 2016 version. I've also added the sample table hope it is fine, I'm not sure I did it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula counts the number of times in that serial with that date and divides it by the number of unique times:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$25,G2,$C$2:$C$25,H2)/SUMPRODUCT((($A$2:$A$25=G2)*($C$2:$C$25=H2))/(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$25,G2,$C$2:$C$25,H2,$B$2:$B$25,$B$2:$B$25)+(($A$2:$A$25<>G2)+($C$2:$C$25<>H2))))
```

[image]

With Office 365 we can do the whole table dynamically:

```
=LET(rng,A2:C25,
    ser,INDEX(rng,,1),
    hr,INDEX(rng,,2),
    dt,INDEX(rng,,3),
    unqdtser,UNIQUE(CHOOSE({1,2},ser,dt)),
    ttlcnt,COUNTIFS(ser,INDEX(unqdtser,,1),dt,INDEX(unqdtser,,2)),
    unq,BYROW(unqdtser,LAMBDA(a,COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(hr,(ser=INDEX(a,,1))*(dt=INDEX(a,,2))))))),
    SORT(CHOOSE({1,1,2},unqdtser,ttlcnt/unq),{1,2}))
```

This formula gets put in the upper left cell of the output and the results will spill.  It will grow and shrink automatically with the data.

[image]